# Open source implementation of "feature density" algorithm

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis, r, algorithm

I'm working on a dataset of house searches - 1 polygon for each area in which people want to find a house from an online search tool.

This produces many overlapping polygons. It would be great to get a basic understanding of the places that are most frequently searched.

You can do this in QGIS and other programs using transparency:

[image]

But ideally, you would create a new layer with the search density for each cell in a grid. This is exactly what the ["feature density" algorithm](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=12441) does in ArcView 3.2 and I've seen it work to great effect. It creates a raster map from a mass of overlaid polygons.

So the question is: is there an implementation of this algorithm for my polygon dataset for open source programs. I'm an R and QGIS user so one of those would be preferable. Many thanks!

Comment: mhh, Can't you just specify an individual integer value for each feature type and then rasterize your vector layer using your newly field? This should return you a raster, where the cells value is the sum of your fields integers and therefore kinda represents density of sth.

Comment: Hi Curlew, that sounds like a sensible solution to me: simple work around. Could you be more specific about which rasterize function (and in which program) you are referring to though. Would it create a new raster layer for each polygon and then add the cell values, or add them all up automatically?.

Answer (score 3):

In GRASS GIS you can achieve the functionality as follows:

- "*Point densities are calculated as the number of points per area*": See http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Count_points_in_polygon (the result is here an absolute result, for density just divide it by area size); or simply use [v.vect.stats](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.vect.stats.html);
- "*Line densities are calculated as the line length per area*": Run [v.build.polylines](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.build.polylines.html) to unite line segments properly. Then cut the lines per area with [v.overlay](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.overlay.html) (see "Line to polygon clipping"). If categories are meaningful (untested here), use [v.to.db](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.to.db.html) to count them and upload to the polygon database table. For density just divide it by area size in a new column ([v.db.update](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.db.update.html));
- "*Polygon densities are calculated as the polygon area per area*": See http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_Overlapping_Areas for an example.

All this can be easily put into a single script. Using the standard GRASS GIS Script parser lines as well, it would auto-generate the GUI, too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've tried to test this but for some reason GRASS doesn't like my data (it loaded other shape files fine). I'll try it again once I've altered the attributes that I think are causing the problem... In the meantime: any ideas how you specify the cell size of the raster output of this approach? That's one of the big advantages of the ArcView 3.2 algorithm.

Comment: What error do you get with that file(s)? For the cell size: obviously you can specify it also in GRASS GIS, see here: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region